# How to set up a common logging framework

Tags: java, logging

I have written a small java application. The application uses some external packages as cling, javax and weld.

In my code I used java.util.logging but the other packages uses other loggers as sl4j.

Question. Is there a way to take control over the logging environment so all packages logging in a simular way. I would like to have a simple way to change loglevel and log output.

//lg

Comment: log4j does a fairly decent job, though it *has* happened that a stubborn library (\*coughbirtcough\*) does its own thing and the only way to make it do what you want is to do it its way.  I don't think there is a way to guarantee it in one simple-to-use library.

Answer (score 0):

[slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) is a logging facade behind which different logging frameworks can be used. For example log4j. You just have to throw it in the path. Log4j can then be configured as usual. There should also be a jul bridge if you want to stick with `java.util.logging`.

Comment: What happens to, for example cling, when I add sl4j to my application. Should not cling still use java.util.logging.